# How do I synchronize animations on an object using A-frame?

Tags: aframe

I have the following code in *index.html*:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

      <!--  Meta  -->
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Alchem Figher!</title>

      <!--  Styles  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">

      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-particle-system@1.0.x/dist/aframe-particle-system-component.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.8.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a-scene>
      <a-text value="Rational Bonding Presents" position="-3 7 -10" color="#EF2D5E">
        <a-text value="Alchem Fighter" height="30" width="20" position=".5 -.5 0" color="#02e8f4"></a-text>
      </a-text>
      <a-sphere id="proton" position="0 2.5 -6" radius=".05" color="#EF2D5E">
        <a-sphere id="eclouds1e1"  radius=".53" color="#02e8f4" opacity=".4">
        <a-entity id="s1e1" material="color: #02e8f4"  rotation="0 90 0"; geometry="primitive: torus; radiusTubular: 0.004" >
          <a-animation attribute="position" dur="250" from=".53 0 0" to="-.53 0 0" direction="alternate" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
          <a-animation attribute="geometry.radius"  dur="125" from=".01" to=".53" direction="alternate" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
        </a-entity>
      </a-sphere>
      <a-sky src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Earth_Western_Hemisphere.jpg"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>

      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The torus id'd: `s1e1`

In here, `<a-entity id="s1e1" material="color: #02e8f4"  rotation="0 90 0"; geometry="primitive: torus; radiusTubular: 0.004" >`, it has two animations attached to it. One for left to right movement, and another for expanding and contracting.

**The question:**

I would like these animations to synchronize so that the torus is expanded in the middle and contracted at the ends. It represents a visualization of an electron orbiting a single proton in a hydrogen atom, but I do not know how to approach that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the process of typing up a response, suggesting the use of the `animation` component (included in `0.9.0` core) rather than `a-animation` (deprecated, and removed in `0.9.0`), which I would still recommend in general practice, but I realized that the animations still do in fact fall out of sync.

I'm assuming this is due to any of the following:

- The extremely short interval (`dur`). The higher you set this, the less noticeable the timing issue.
- A difference in overhead due to how the animated properties are targeted, e.g., raw property vs. attribute (using `setAttribute` under the hood).
- IIRC, loops are set with either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` under the hood. Rather than rely on this, you may want to disable looping and trigger these animations by emitting a timed event so you can guarantee that they're executed simultaneously. You can create a custom component that does this using a throttled `tick` handler, `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

I also suggest using either `linear` or `easeInOutQuad` for the easing as the default setting only eases in one direction, which can cause an undesirable effect.

Either way, you may want to submit this as a bug to the A-Frame repo: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/new